# How to transfer contact from android mobile(with broken screen) to my laptop

Tags: contacts, data-recovery, mobile-data, broken-screen, data-transfer

I know there is a bunch of third party apps is available to transfer contacts but my android phone's display not working so I can not handle UI of those apps.

I found this **[MOBOROBO](http://download.cnet.com/MoboRobo/3000-18511_4-75647777.html)** but it also requires some UI actions

Is there any solution for that using USB?? or any laptop software?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Were the contacts not synced to a Google account?

Comment: Apart from that, have you already checked with our [broken-screen tag-wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info)? It has that topic covered.